# How can we export selected features from multple shapefiles in a single step

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-query

I have made a spatial query in ArcGIS where i am selecting features from multiple layers from a single source.

How can I export all the selected features from multiple layers at a single step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the selections made on the layers, you can right click your destination geodatabase and select import multiple feature classes.

The selections will remain, and your imported features will be based off the selection